# modify the body text of existing function objects

Tags: r

I have some .Rdata files that contain saved functions as defined by approxfun().

Some of the save files pre-date the change to approxfun from package "base" to "stats", and so the body has

```
PACKAGE = "base"
```

and the wrong package causes the function to fail. I can fix(myfun) and simply replace "base" with "stats", but I want a neater automatic way.

Can I do this with gsub() and body() somehow?

I can get the body text and substitute there with

```
as.character(body(myfun))
```

but I don't know how to turn that back into a "call" and replace the definition.

(I know that a better solution is to have saved the data originally used by approxfun and simply recreate the function, but I wonder if there's a sensible way to modify the existing one.)

Edit: I found it here

[What ways are there to edit a function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458013/what-ways-are-there-to-edit-a-function-in-r/2485556#2485556)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What ways are there to edit a function in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458013/what-ways-are-there-to-edit-a-function-in-r)

Comment: I tried `body(foo)  <- gsub("PACKAGE = 'base'", "PACKAGE = 'stats'", body(foo))` for you, but body() doesn't return text so you can't use text manipulation to change it. I verified this with @MrFlick

Comment: could you then write your own answer so that this post is no longer "unanswered" ?

Comment: Nah. It's your itch why don't you scratch it,?

Comment: I didn't ever think passive-aggressive refusing to answer questions would be a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `substitute` function.

For example:

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {
  result <- list(x+y,x*y)
  return(result)
}
```

Using `body`, treat `myfun` as a list to select what you would like to change in the function:

```
> body(myfun)[[2]][[3]][[2]]
x + y
```

When you change this, you must use the `substitute` function so you replace the part of the function with a `call` or `name` object, as appropriate. Replacing with character strings doesn't work since functions are not stored as or operated on as character strings.

```
body(myfun)[[2]][[3]][[2]] <- substitute(2*x)
```

Now the selected piece of the function has been replaced:

```
> myfun
function (x, y) 
{
    result <- list(2 * x, x * y)
    return(result)
}
```