# combination of expand.grid and mapply?

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to come up with a variant of `mapply` (call it `xapply` for now) that combines the functionality (sort of) of `expand.grid` and `mapply`.  That is, for a function `FUN` and a list of arguments `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, ... of *unknown length*, it should produce a list of length `n1*n2*n3` (where `ni` is the length of list `i`) which is the result of applying `FUN` to all combinations of the elements of the list.

If `expand.grid` worked to generate lists of lists rather than data frames, one might be able to use it, but I have in mind that the lists may be lists of things that won't necessarily fit into a data frame nicely.

This function works OK if there are exactly three lists to expand, but I am curious about a more generic solution.  (`FLATTEN` is unused, but I can imagine that `FLATTEN=FALSE` would generate nested lists rather than a single list ...)

```
xapply3 <- function(FUN,L1,L2,L3,FLATTEN=TRUE,MoreArgs=NULL) {
  retlist <- list()
  count <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(L1)) {
    for (j in seq_along(L2)) {
      for (k in seq_along(L3)) {
        retlist[[count]] <- do.call(FUN,c(list(L1[[i]],L2[[j]],L3[[k]]),MoreArgs))
        count <- count+1
      }
    }
  }
  retlist
}
```

**edit:** forgot to return the result.  One might be able to solve this by making a list of the indices with `combn` and going from there ...

Comment: I may be missing something, but it sounds like an easy job for `plyr::m*ply` (together with `expand.grid`).

Comment: OK.  I think data frames and `expand.grid` might be more flexible than I think ...

Comment: See a related function here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192848/210673, based on what outer does.

Comment: hmm.  Reason for downvote, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution to my own question, but perhaps someone can do better (and I haven't implemented `FLATTEN=FALSE` ...)

```
xapply <- function(FUN,...,FLATTEN=TRUE,MoreArgs=NULL) {
  L <- list(...)
  inds <- do.call(expand.grid,lapply(L,seq_along)) ## Marek's suggestion
  retlist <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(inds)) {
    arglist <- mapply(function(x,j) x[[j]],L,as.list(inds[i,]),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    if (FLATTEN) {
      retlist[[i]] <- do.call(FUN,c(arglist,MoreArgs))
    }
  }
  retlist
}
```

**edit**: I tried @baptiste's suggestion, but it's not easy (or wasn't for me). The closest I got was

```
xapply2 <- function(FUN,...,FLATTEN=TRUE,MoreArgs=NULL) {
  L <- list(...)
  xx <- do.call(expand.grid,L)
  f <- function(...) {
    do.call(FUN,lapply(list(...),"[[",1))
  }
  mlply(xx,f)
}
```

which still doesn't work. `expand.grid` is indeed more flexible than I thought (although it creates a weird data frame that can't be printed), but enough magic is happening inside `mlply` that I can't quite make it work.

Here is a test case:

```
L1 <- list(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),
           data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10)),
           data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10)))

L2 <- list(y~1,y~x,y~poly(x,2))          
z <- xapply(lm,L2,L1)
xapply(lm,L2,L1)
```

Comment: Shorthand: `inds <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(L, seq_along))`

Comment: @ben-bolker, the second example doesn't work because `expand.grid` produces a dataframe. Since your test feeds in unnamed arguments to `xapply2`, `expand.grid` uses the default column names. However, this means that the second `do.call` also uses the default names as named arguments to the function you're testing (`lm`). Doing `xapply2(lm, data=L1,formula=L2)` should run without issue. (sorry--I know this is old, but it haunted me for a good chunk of time :)

Answer (score 1):

@ben-bolker, I had a similar desire and think I have a preliminary solution worked out, that I've also tested to work in parallel. The function, which I somewhat confusingly called `gmcmapply` (g for grid) takes an arbitrarily large named list `mvars` (that gets `expand.grid`-ed within the function) and a `FUN` that utilizes the list names as if they were arguments to the function itself (`gmcmapply` will update the formals of `FUN` so that by the time `FUN` is passed to `mcmapply` it's arguments reflect the variables that the user would like to iterate over (which would be layers in a nested for loop)). `mcmapply` then dynamically updates the values of these formals as it cycles over the expanded set of variables in `mvars`.

I've posted the preliminary code as [a gist (reprinted with an example below)](https://gist.github.com/natehall329/91233468214cb17253780fa0c59ee1af) and would be curious to get your feedback on it. I'm a grad student, that is self-described as an intermediately-skilled R enthusiast, so this is pushing my R skills for sure. You or other folks in the community may have suggestions that would improve on what I have. I do think even as it stands, I'll be coming to this function quite a bit in the future.

```
gmcmapply <- function(mvars, FUN, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, mc.cores = 1, ...){
  require(parallel)

  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  funArgs <- formals(FUN)[which(names(formals(FUN)) != "...")] # allow for default args to carry over from FUN.

  expand.dots <- list(...) # allows for expanded dot args to be passed as formal args to the user specified function

  # Implement non-default arg substitutions passed through dots.
  if(any(names(funArgs) %in% names(expand.dots))){
    dot_overwrite <- names(funArgs[which(names(funArgs) %in% names(expand.dots))])
    funArgs[dot_overwrite] <- expand.dots[dot_overwrite]

    #for arg naming and matching below.
    expand.dots[dot_overwrite] <- NULL
  }

  ## build grid of mvars to loop over, this ensures that each combination of various inputs is evaluated (equivalent to creating a structure of nested for loops)
  grid <- expand.grid(mvars,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # specify formals of the function to be evaluated  by merging the grid to mapply over with expanded dot args
  argdefs <- rep(list(bquote()), ncol(grid) + length(expand.dots) + length(funArgs) + 1)
  names(argdefs) <- c(colnames(grid), names(funArgs), names(expand.dots), "...")

  argdefs[which(names(argdefs) %in% names(funArgs))] <- funArgs # replace with proper dot arg inputs.
  argdefs[which(names(argdefs) %in% names(expand.dots))] <- expand.dots # replace with proper dot arg inputs.

  formals(FUN) <- argdefs

  if(SIMPLIFY) {
    #standard mapply
    do.call(mcmapply, c(FUN, c(unname(grid), mc.cores = mc.cores))) # mc.cores = 1 == mapply
  } else{
    #standard Map
    do.call(mcmapply, c(FUN, c(unname(grid), SIMPLIFY = FALSE, mc.cores = mc.cores)))
  }
}
```

example code below:

```
      # Example 1:
      # just make sure variables used in your function appear as the names of mvars
      myfunc <- function(...){
        return_me <- paste(l3, l1^2 + l2, sep = "_")
        return(return_me)
      }

      mvars <- list(l1 = 1:10,
                    l2 = 1:5,
                    l3 = letters[1:3])


      ### list output (mapply)
      lreturns <- gmcmapply(mvars, myfunc)

      ### concatenated output (Map)
      lreturns <- gmcmapply(mvars, myfunc, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

      ## N.B. This is equivalent to running:
      lreturns <- c()
      for(l1 in 1:10){
        for(l2 in 1:5){
          for(l3 in letters[1:3]){
            lreturns <- c(lreturns,myfunc(l1,l2,l3))
          }
        }
      }

      ### concatenated outout run on 2 cores.
      lreturns <- gmcmapply(mvars, myfunc, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, mc.cores = 2)

     Example 2. Pass non-default args to FUN.
     ## Since the apply functions dont accept full calls as inputs (calls are internal), user can pass arguments to FUN through dots, which can overwrite a default option for FUN.
     # e.g. apply(x,1,FUN) works and apply(x,1,FUN(arg_to_change= not_default)) does not, the correct way to specify non-default/additional args to FUN is:
     # gmcmapply(mvars, FUN, arg_to_change = not_default)

     ## update myfunc to have a default argument
      myfunc <- function(rep_letters = 3, ...){
        return_me <- paste(rep(l3, rep_letters), l1^2 + l2, sep = "_")
        return(return_me)
      }

      lreturns <- gmcmapply(mvars, myfunc, rep_letters = 1)
```

A bit of additional functionality I would like to add but am still trying to work out is

1. cleaning up the output to be a pretty nested list with the names of mvars (normally, I'd create multiple lists within a nested for loop and tag lower-level lists onto higher level lists all the way up until all layers of the gigantic nested loop were done). I think using some abstracted variant of the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264739/convert-nested-data-frame-to-a-hierarchical-list) will work, but I haven't figured out how to make the solution flexible to the number of columns in the `expand.grid`-ed data.frame.
2. I would like an option to log the outputs of the child processesthat get called in `mcmapply` in a user-specified directory. So you could look at .txt outputs from every combination of variables generated by `expand.grid` (i.e. if the user prints model summaries or status messages as a part of `FUN` as I often do). I think a feasible solution is to use the `substitute()` and `body()` functions, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971419/modify-the-body-text-of-existing-function-objects) to edit `FUN` to open a `sink()` at the beginning of `FUN` and close it at the end if the user specifies a directory to write to. Right now, I just program it right into `FUN` itself, but later it would be nice to just pass `gmcmapply` an argument called something like `log_children = "path_to_log_dir`. and then editing the body of the function to (pseudocode) `sink(file = file.path(log_children, paste0(paste(names(mvars), sep = "_"), ".txt")`

Let me know what you think!

-Nate