# elementwise combination of two lists in R

Tags: r, elementwise-operations

Say I have two lists:

```
list.a <- as.list(c("a", "b", "c"))

list.b <- as.list(c("d", "e", "f"))
```

I would like to combine these lists recursively, such that the result would be a list of combined elements as a vector like the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] a d

[[2]]
[1] a e

[[3]]
[1] a f

[[4]]
[1] b d
```

and so on. I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple here. Any help?

Cheers.

Comment: `expand.grid(list.a, list.b)` will give you what you want in a `data.frame` structure, which is arguably more useful.

Comment: I need the resultant list for do.call to generate a series of plots with the x to be the elements of list.a, and the y to be the elements of list.b (i.e., a[1], b[1]; a[1], b[2]; ...; a[n], b[k]).

Comment: see also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515134/combination-of-expand-grid-and-mapply

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`expand.grid(list.a, list.b)` gives you the desired result in a `data.frame`. This tends to be the most useful format for working with data in R. However, you could get the exact structure you ask for (save the ordering) with a call to `apply` and `lapply`:

```
result.df <- expand.grid(list.a, list.b)
result.list <- lapply(apply(result.df, 1, identity), unlist)
```

If you want this list ordered by the first element:

```
result.list <- result.list[order(sapply(result.list, head, 1))]
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. What is k?

Comment: +1 -- Nice to see that `expand.grid()` works on lists as well as "simpler" vectors.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks! I find it strange there is not a built in function to recursively combine lists. Am I alone here?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if each list contains multiple sub-elements per element. For example, if `list.a` were instead `list.a <- list(c("a","b","c"),c("x","y","z"))`, one does not get the desired result...

Answer (score 11):

You want `mapply` (if by "recursively" you mean "in parallel"):

```
mapply(c, list.a, list.b, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Or maybe this is more what you want:

```
unlist(lapply(list.a, function(a) lapply(list.b, function (b) c(a, b))), recursive=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7):

Surprised nobody has mentioned this simple one liner:

```
as.list(outer(list.a,list.b, paste))

[[1]]
[1] "a d"

[[2]]
[1] "b d"

[[3]]
[1] "c d"

[[4]]
[1] "a e"
```

Comment: This seems to coerce the input into strings.  I tried this with integers, `x <- c(1, 2, 3)` and `y <- c(4, 5, 6)`, and it changes everything into strings.

Answer (score 4):

This gets you what you are looking for:

```
unlist(lapply(list.a, function(X) {
    lapply(list.b, function(Y) {
        c(X, Y)
    })
}), recursive=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function you can pass lists to to expand

```
expand.list <- function(...){
   lapply(as.data.frame(t((expand.grid(...)))),c, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)}

 expand.list(list.a, list.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat brute force approach that will, given they are the same dimensions, append list.b to list.a recursively using the append function.

```
# CREATE LIST OBJECTS 
  list.a <- as.list(c("a", "b", "c"))
  list.b <- as.list(c("d", "e", "f"))

# CREATE AN EMPTY LIST TO POPULATE      
list.ab <- list()

# DOUBLE LOOP TO CREATE RECURSIVE COMBINATIONS USING append
    ct=0    
      for( i in 1:length(list.a) ) {    
        for (j in 1:length(list.b) ) {
          ct=ct+1
           list.ab[[ct]] <- append(list.a[[i]], list.b[[j]])     
         } 
       }

# PRINT RESULTS
list.ab
```