# Pasting together two vectors in R elementwise

Tags: r, paste

I am trying to build a web scraper that'll go through a number of websites and extract some information. In order to do this, I'm going to need to make a list of the last couple of characters in the url, so I can map the information into a data frame. To do this, I've found out that the end of the url should have a number between 1 and 10 to identify a department, and a given character to identify a unit. Therefore I've made two vectors with the needed units and department IDs:

```
departments <- c(1, 2, 9, 10)
units <- c("A", "B", "C", "F", "I", "O", "V")
```

To go through each website, I need a list that combines these two vectors in each possible way, like for instance "1A", "1B", "1C", "1F", "1I", "1O", "1V", "2A" and so forth.

```
I've tried different solutions, but they do not return what I expected, like for instance:
> depUn <- as.list(paste(departments, units, sep = ""))
> depUn
[[1]]
[1] "1A"

[[2]]
[1] "2B"

[[3]]
[1] "9C"

[[4]]
[1] "10F"

[[5]]
[1] "1I"

[[6]]
[1] "2O"

[[7]]
[1] "9V"
```

Does someone have any good insight to how I could solve this?

**EDIT**
I've already tried the `expand.grid` option, and while it was succesful in putting the elements after one another in a list, it failed to put them together in one string. Can someone help me how to accomplish this? Here's and excerpt of the code and results I tried back then:

```
> dfDepUn <- expand.grid(departments, units)
> DepUn <- lapply(apply(dfDepUn, 1, identity), unlist)
> dfDepUn
[[1]]
Var1 Var2 
 "1"  "A" 

[[2]]
Var1 Var2 
 "2"  "A" 

[[3]]
Var1 Var2 
 "9"  "A" 

[[4]]
Var1 Var2 
"10"  "A"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018173/elementwise-combination-of-two-lists-in-r

Comment: `as.list(outer(departments, units, paste0))`

Comment: [How to cross-paste strings (each-to-each)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154318/how-to-cross-paste-strings-each-to-each)

Comment: Thanks @Henrik that was exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
df <- expand.grid(departments, units)
as.list(paste0(df$Var1, df$Var2))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already, as I just edited in my original question. But Henrik provided the answer I needed in the comments