# Convert nested data.frame to a hierarchical list

Tags: r, tidyr

Is there a neat way to convert a nested data.frame to a hierarchical list?

I do it below with a for loop, but ideally there is a neater solution that generalizes to an arbitrary number of nested columns.

```
nested_df <- expand.grid(V1 = c('a','b','c'),
                         V2 = c('z','y'))%>%
    group_by_all()%>%
    do(x=runif(10))%>%
    ungroup

nested_ls <- list()
for(v1 in unique(nested_df$V1)){
    for(v2 in unique(nested_df$V2)){
        nested_ls[[v1]][[v2]] <- nested_df%>%
            filter(V1==v1 & V2==v2)%>%
            pull(x)%>%
            unlist
    }
}

str(nested_ls)
```

Comment: Did you mean `expand.grid`?

Comment: @Sotos there is `tidyr::expand_grid` :D

Comment: @RonakShah what the hell are they trying to do to us?? :)

Comment: yes, `expand.grid`. corrected the Q.  `tidyr::expand_grid` that didn't use factors would be handy though.

Comment: All I can think of is some version of nested loops, and I don't find those easy to generalize to more nesting variables.  From what I've seen it looks like most questions are about going from a nested list to a data.frame, and not the other way around. :D  You might consider adding info on what you need this structure for in case there is a whole different approach (i.e., this could be an X-Y problem :) ).

Comment: In this case, when I'm working interactively, its easier to access the nested data when its in a hierarchical list. e.g. nested_ls$a$y. And I have scripts that expect this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not very strict with the names `z` and `y`, and can also work with `[[1]]` and `[[2]]`, then you can directly do,

```
split(nested_df$x, nested_df$V1)
```

If you need the names, then

```
lapply(split(nested_df, nested_df$V1), function(i)split(i$x, i$V2))

#Or as @Frank mentions in comments, we can use setNames
lapply(split(nested_df, nested_df$V1), function(i) setNames(i$x, i$V2))
```

Comment: names are necessary in my case.  The first `lapply` option seems to create an extra level of hierarchy for `z` and `y`. The 2nd `lapply` works.

Comment: How would you generalize to more than 2 nested columns?