# Add a line to the body text of existing function objects

Tags: r, function

In the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089312/3362993) we have an original function.

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {
  result <- list(x+y,x*y)
  return(result)
}
```

They replace the second line of the function with `result <- list(2 * x, x * y)` by running:

`body(myfun)[[2]][[3]][[2]] <- substitute(2*x)`

What I am looking to do is **add** a line to the function instead of replacing to get something like:

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {
  print(x)
  result <- list(x+y,x*y)
  return(result)
}
```

Is this possible? I have tried a whole raft of `substitute`, `bquote`, `eval`, `parse`, `quote`, and `expression` commands.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458377/3362993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may manipulate the body of your function using `body()`.

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {
  result <- list(x+y,x*y)
  return(result)
}
myfun
# function(x,y) {
#   result <- list(x+y,x*y)
#   return(result)
# }

b <- body(myfun)  ## for covenience
b
as.list(b)
# [[1]]
# `{`
# 
# [[2]]
# result <- list(x + y, x * y)
# 
# [[3]]
# return(result)
```

The body can be handled similar to a list. The `print(x)` line can be `c`oncatenated as an `expression` to the original elements. Put it back `as.call` to the body.

```
body(myfun) <- as.call(c(b[[1]], expression(print(x)), b[[2]], b[[3]]))
myfun
# function (x, y) 
# {
#   print(x)  ## voilà!
#   result <- list(x + y, x * y)
#   return(result)
# }
```

*Test:*

```
myfun(1, 2)
# [1] 1
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```