# Change internal function of a package

Tags: r, package

Some background:

I have to use function `HMR` from package `HMR` a lot. Unfortunately, this function is very slow. (`HMR` is essentially a fitting function, which is designed to be as robust as possible, which is one reason for the lack of efficiency.) Function `HMR` calls function `HMR::.HMR.fit1`, which does the actual fitting.
Using `Rprof` I know that the main problem regarding efficiency is the use of `lsfit`, which gets called a lot. Therefore, I modified the code of `.HMR.fit1` to call the C function used by `lsfit` directly without all the overhead of `lsfit`, which should result in a substantial speed gain.

Now I would like to substitute `HMR::.HMR.fit1` with my modified function and test `HMR` if it gives the same results and how much speed I gain.

I tried to do this:

```
mod.fun <- function(<many args>) {
 <a lot of code>
}
environment(mod.fun) <- environment(.HMR.fit1)
.HMR.fit1 <- mod.fun
```

However, `HMR::.HMR.fit1` is not changed by doing this and apparently `HMR::HMR` does not use my modified fitting function. Is there a way to achieve what I want without building the package from source, which I cannot do due to user rights restrictions on my (windows) computer?

Right now, my solution would be to copy the code of `HMR::HMR`, but I hope there is a more convenient solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
?assignInNamespace
```

to replace `.HMR.fit1` in the `HMR` package with your version.

Possible duplicate of :

[How do I override a non-visible function in the package namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743390/how-do-i-override-a-non-visible-function-in-the-package-namespace)

Comment: If you want to *add* new function instead of modifying the old, use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3402159/684229

Answer (score 8):

For a quick testing you can use the `trace` function with `edit=TRUE` to modify the function, this will do the replacing in the proper namespace and also allow you to use `untrace` to revert the function back to the original.  These changes will not last beyond the current session.