# Naming columns of coefficient matrix in a VAR

Tags: r, naming, var

I am searching for a fast and simple way to give comprehensible names to the columns of a VAR-coefficient matrix.

What I would like to use is the function `VAR.names`, which is used in the function `VAR.est()` in the `VAR.etp-package`. When I use the function `VAR.est()`, this works perfectly, but as soon as I modify `VAR.est` (by adding another element to the list of values which are returned), I receive an error message stating *"could not find function VAR.names"*.

I could not find any information on the function VAR.names.

Example:

```
library(VAR.etp)  
data(dat)  
M=VAR.est(dat,p=2,type="const")  
M$coef
```

Another possibility would be to use a loop as in the function `VAR()` from the vars package, but if `VAR.names` would actually work, this would be a lot more elegant!

Comment: I believe this old question of mine should be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12178830/1412059

Comment: That function is likely not exported from the package. You can specify it with `VAR.etp:::VAR.names`. That should allow you to use the function outside the namespace of the package.