# How to change the default background colour for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel, background-color

I'm trying to change the default panel background colour in the ggplot2 package install on my computer. The current default is `'grey90'`, and I want to change it to `'#E8EDFB'`.

I tried to do this by changing the default theme ggplot2 uses, `theme_grey`.

Using either

```
fixInNamespace("theme_grey", pos="package:ggplot2")
```

or

```
fixInNamespace("theme_grey", ns="ggplot2")
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743390/how-do-i-override-a-non-visible-function-in-the-package-namespace), gives me a nice editor where I can change the relevant bit of code:

```
panel.background =   element_rect(fill = "grey90", colour = NA)
```

I changed `"grey90"` to `'#E8EDFB'` and saved. Whenever I re-run one of the commands above, I now again get the editor which indeed shows my edited code instead of the original. However, when I run `theme_grey`, I just get the original code outputed to my console, not my changed code, and the panel backgrounds on my plots are also still grey.

How do I get my plot panel backgrounds to default to `#E8EDFB` instead of grey?

NOTE: I want to change the default permanently, not just change the color for one plot or for the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
theme_set(theme_grey() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="red")))
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't give me exactly what I want: when I ran your code and then created a plot, the panel background was indeed red, but when I closed the session and restarted R my panel backgrounds were back grey. I'm hoping to change the default permanently.

Comment: if you want something permanent, you can either i) place the above in your .Rprofile; ii) fork+edit the ggplot2 package before installing it. For consistency with other people using my code, I prefer to just put this one line at the top of my scripts though.