# remove \begin{tabular} from Stargazer .tex output

Tags: r, latex, tabular, stargazer

Is there a simple way to automatically remove the

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc}
```

and

```
\end{tabular}
```

lines at the beginning and end of a Stargazer LaTeX output?

Indeed, I just need the inside LaTeX code and removing those lines manually from the TeX file generated by stargazer is a complete loss of time...

Comment: I usually just write python scripts to take the initial output of stargazer and modify it as I need.  I find this is often easier than wrangling with stargazer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the functions defined to create the LaTeX output in [`stargazer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/index.html) are defined within the (internal) wrapper function `.stargazer.wrap`. As such, it's not that easy to update the components automatically. You'll either have to make a copy of the package that you maintain locally, or edit the `.stargazer.wrap` function every time you load the package.

Here's how to do the latter, following the guidelines from [How do I override a non-visible function in the package namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8743390/914686) (managing your own copy would entail something similar):

1. Load `stargazer`:

   ```
   > library(stargazer)
   ```
2. Edit the `.stargazer.wrap` function inside the `stargazer` namespace/package:

   ```
   > fixInNamespace(".stargazer.wrap", pos="package:stargazer")
   ```
3. Find and remove at least rows 4206-4207 from the `.data.frame.table.header` function:

   [image]

   These two lines are used to print the `tabular` header.
4. Find and remove at least row 3385 in the `.publish.table` function:

   [image]

   This line prints `\end{tabular}` (plus a line break).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, I ended up just adding some lines to my `R` code after having created the table with `stargazer`:

```
filename <- paste0("./my/path/", dplyr::last(list.files("./my/path/"))) # always loads the last file
lines <- readLines(filename) # read file
lines[1:4] <- ""           # I wanted to replace the first four lines
lines[length(lines)] <- "" # as well as the last line
```

Hope this helps.