# how to change the colour in addMACD of quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I am new to R and quantmod ,  thanks for any help.
I want to change the colour of mace graph in quantmod.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
chartSeries(AAPL)
addMACD()   # this works
```

But
addMACD(col = c('red','blue', 'green', 'black') get the following errors.

> addMACD(col = c('red','blue, yellow'))
>   Error in ifelse((macd[, 1] - macd[, 2]) > 0, col[1], col[2]) : 
>     replacement has length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
>     'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

and according the manual of quantmod, addMACD has the colour options.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that is a bug in the `addMACD` function.

If you look at its source code (e.g. with `fix(addMACD)`) you will see that it does:

```
col <- if (missing(col)) 
        col <- c("#999999", "#777777", "#BBBBBB", "#FF0000")
```

Hence, if you define `col`, the above lines assigns NULL to `col`.

If you change those lines to

```
if (missing(col)) 
        col <- c("#999999", "#777777", "#BBBBBB", "#FF0000")
```

or just delete them altogether and specify a default value for `col` the function will work as expected.

You may want to have a look at this (and related discussions) on how to edit a function in R: [What ways are there to edit a function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458013/what-ways-are-there-to-edit-a-function-in-r)

Comment: Great! Not no only addMACD works, but also addTA(stoch(kdj, nFastK=9, nFastD=3, nSlowD=3, maType ='EMA'), on = NA, col = c('red','blue','black')) works. Thx.