# data.table's fread() giving unwanted download message

Tags: r, data.table

I'm not too familiar with data.table's `fread` function, but it makes quick work of reading my data, so now I'm intrigued.  At URL `"http://www.retrosheet.org/CurrentNames.csv"`, there is a simple csv file.  The following two calls work fine.

```
readLines("http://www.retrosheet.org/CurrentNames.csv", n = 2)
# [1] "ANA,LAA,AL,,Los Angeles,Angels,,4/11/1961,9/1/1965,Los Angeles,CA"
# [2] "ANA,CAL,AL,,California,Angels,,9/2/1965,9/29/1968,Anaheim,CA"
rcsv <- read.csv("http://www.retrosheet.org/CurrentNames.csv", header = FALSE)
```

But `fread` is delivering a download message, and I can't seem to turn it off with

```
showProgress = FALSE
```

I could use `suppressMessages()`, but I don't really want to.

```
library(data.table)
dtf <- fread("http://www.retrosheet.org/CurrentNames.csv", 
             header = FALSE, showProgress = FALSE)
# trying URL 'http://www.retrosheet.org/CurrentNames.csv'
# Content type 'text/plain' length 7729 bytes
# opened URL
# ==================================================
# downloaded 7729 bytes
```

Can anyone explain this, and can I turn it off in the `fread` arguments?

It looks like a call to `download.file` has occurred somewhere. Why wouldn't `fread` just read the URL the same way as `read.csv`?

Comment: :) how do you imagine you can "read straight from URL" and not download? But this is a good FR to add `quiet=TRUE` to `download.file` if `showProgress` is `FALSE` - you should add it to github.

Comment: @eddi - That was a bit of sarcasm, we did that conversation yesterday. :) But I also think a `quiet = TRUE` option would be a good addition to `fread`. And in all honesty, I'm not real versed on memory, storage, remote servers, etc.  I just like baseball and R so I'm writing a kind of "learn as I go" package.

Comment: [Feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/741) submitted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update Oct 2014**. Now in v1.9.5 :

> `fread` now passes `showProgress=FALSE` through to `download.file()` as `quiet=!showProgress`. Thanks to a pull request from Karl Broman and Richard Scriven for filing the issue, [#741](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/741).

---

Previous answer ...

It does download the file, here is the part of the code that does it.

```
else if (substring(input, 1, 7) %chin% c("http://", "https:/", 
    "file://")) {
    tt = tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(tt), add = TRUE)
    download.file(input, tt)
    input = tt
}
```

My guess this is because fread makes more than one pass at the file, first to get the structure, then to actually read the whole thing in. Saves downloading multiple times.

Comment: What we need is a `quiet = TRUE` passed to `download.file`

Comment: Well, you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458013/what-ways-are-there-to-edit-a-function-in-r

Comment: I guess I could edit it and call it something else. I'm going to be using it in a few package functions so I may need to keep it as is as well.

Comment: @RichardScriven What do you mean it's disguised as a URL. It's a file that lives on a remote server. Both `readLines` and `read.csv` are also downloading the file. They are just processing it as a stream (you have to be able to read the whole thing in memory).