# Create a default comment header template in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a default comment header template in R for all new scripts?

I generally include some standard info at the top of all my scripts and would like to automate the process of creating the comment header.

For example:

```
##################################################
## Project:
## Script purpose:
## Date:
## Author:
##################################################
```

Comment: Assuming you are using rstudio (R and rstudio are independent pieces of software), you may have a look at the relatively new code snippets feature in rstudio, outlined [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets). It is not exactly right, but might get you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is actually a better option since it will allow me to make (and easily insert) comment headers with different formats (e.g. for function scripts, cleanup scripts, shiny apps, etc)

Comment: Also, @lmo please upvote the question if you found it interesting/useful!

Answer (score 12):

Following the suggestion from @lmo above, I created two new code snippets in RStudio by editing the snippets file located at `Preferences > Code > Edit Snippets`

***Note:*** Code below the snippet definition must be indented using **tab** and not two spaces

**Snippet 1: Comment header for new scripts**

```
snippet header_script
  ##################################################
  ## Project:
  ## Script purpose:
  ## Date:
  ## Author:
  ##################################################
```

**Snippet 2: Comment header for sections of code within a script:**

```
snippet header_section
  ## Section:
  ##################################################
```

Now, whenever I want to insert a given header, I just start typing the snippet name (e.g. `header_script`), select it from the autocomplete menu (do **not** type out in full), and hit enter to insert the comment header.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can do it directly, but you may be able to approximate it by putting the following in your Rprofile.

```
make_r_template <- function(filename = "r_template.R", dir = getwd())
{
  if (file.exists(file.path(dir, filename))) invisible(NULL)
  else{
    write(c("##################################################",
            "## Project:",
            "## Script purpose:",
            "## Date:",
            "## Author:",
            "##################################################"),
          file = file.path(dir, filename),
          sep = "\n")
  }
}

make_r_template()
```

This will run every time R starts and write the blank template to the working directory, so long as it doesn't exist.  You could also run the function at any point with a different `filename` value to create a blank template elsewhere.

A nice supplemental touch would be a second function that looks at a file, attempts to identify the header, and inserts it if the header is not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **vim** you could define a snippet like this [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips) one in a separate R-snippet file:

```
snippet header "R Header template" b
#' ---
#' title:  ${1:title here}
#' author: ${2:John Smith (John@Smith.com)}
#' date:   ${3:`date +%Y-%m-%d`}
#' ---
endsnippet
```

You would only have to type `header<tab>` which is a massive time-saver especially since it fills in predefined values (such date).

This seems also Rmarkdown compatible as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927660/using-rmarkdownrender-to-set-document-header-title-author-date).