# By default open script with header in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi I'm wondering if there is a way to make RStudio's default new R script have a header? I.e. change the script that opens when you press ctrl + shift + n to include text without any other user input.

For example:

```
## Project:
## Purpose:
## Created By: 
## Created Date:
```

I know I can add a snippet with a similar set up as shown in this question [Create a default comment header template in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616132/create-a-default-comment-header-template-in-r) but I'm hoping there is a way to make all new scripts in RStudio open this by default, similar to the way Spyder defaults to having a "Created on … Author..." at the top of each new script.

The idea being that it is a reminder to myself and other people in the organisation that we require headers on our scripts. Having a snippet makes it easier but doesn't serve as a reminder.

Thanks

Comment: Project templates are as close as you're going to come w/o modifying the source of RStudio itself https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable suggestion that sounds straight-forward to implement (never say "easy"). Perhaps you could request it? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Answer (score 1):

That is possible, at least with RStudio.

You can save your default script in "C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\templates\default.R" (for Windows default settings).

This file will not exist in the beginning, so just have to create it. Probably also the templates folder.

RStudio will open all new R scripts with this default setting.