# Modify function in global environment

Tags: r, function, environment

Not sure if this is possible but worth an ask. I need to be able to modify a function that is loaded into the global environment. For example, lets say I had a function like the below that returned the median of a vector

```
myVec<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10)

average<-function(x){
  median(x)
}

average(myVec)
```

Now I wanted to update the function to return the mean but without changing the overall structure of the function so I want to update `average()` so it becomes

```
average<-function(x){
  mean(x)
}
```

Is this possible? I'm guessing some form of writing the function to a temp file and calling `readLines()` and `writeLines()` but as of yet I've not had any success.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the entire body of the function, there's `body(average) <- quote(mean(x))`. Rewriting an existing function at a finer level can get messy, I guess.

Comment: If you define a function twice the more recent one overwrites the older one so the more recent one will be used.

Comment: The function I need to modify is more complex so I don't want to just redefine it. I need just modify one line from it being in memory and then append it to a list and save the list.

Comment: Self-modifying code tends to be very hard to debug. Normally instead one would define the original function to have the replaceable functionality be passed as an argument.  That argument could itself be a function.

Comment: Nice one thanks @Frank

Comment: True, this is a bit of a patch to a bunch of stored objects that I need to read into memory so not quite 'normal' :)

Comment: What do you even mean by "the overall structure of the function"? I don't see how changing just the body of the function is any different than overwriting the function.

Comment: I mean no changing the parameters, otherwise you could just have a argument to amend the code. `fun<-function(myVec,myAverage)`

Comment: Maybe you could give an example where the "structure" matters. It could be as simple/silly as `average = function(x){1+1; median(x)}` If your function is simple enough, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458013/

Comment: Even better @Frank thanks

Comment: If the function has more than just a call to `median`, make sure you only replace the single function call and not the entire body.  In this case, `body(average)[[2]][[1]] <- quote(mean)` is all you want to do.

Comment: Maybe also check out the 'trace' function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean a closure:

```
myVec<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10)

# this will create your function
create.average <- function (fun) {
  my.average <- function (x) {
    fun(x)
  }
  return(my.average)
}
# define average as mean
average <- create.average(mean)
average(myVec)
mean(myVec) # only to verify result

# re-define average as median
average <- create.average(median)
average(myVec)
median(myVec) # only to verify result
```

Comment: Sorry not what I'm after. Frank has it with `body(average) <- quote(mean(x))`